# USB boot issue in pc unit with atom based processor

Tags: android, intel

I want to install android os on my intel based PC unit [link](http://www.nexcom.com/Products/mobile-computing-solutions/in-vehicle-pc/in-vehicle-pc/in-vehicle-computer-vtc-1010). I am trying to install android kitkat image which is released by intel [link](https://01.org/android-ia/downloads/android-4.4.2r1-ia2). As instructions stated [quick start](https://01.org/android-ia/guides/quick-start) I am booting the USB in UEFI mode. But the unit is not booting the USB. I have also tried the USB on my core i3 processor and I am able to boot the usb. Can anyone help me to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Can you see the USB Drive in the UEFI/BIOS Menue?

Is your USB Drive attached to a USB 3.0 Port? Have you already tried a USB 2.0 Port?

I already had problems with USB 3.0 Port and boot in UEFI mode...

Comment: yes I can see the pendrive in BIOS menu. My perdrive is attached to USB 2.0 port.

Comment: When i look in your quick start man i only see: Make sure "UEFI Boot Support" is enabled in the BIOS. / So i think you only have to enable this option an then boot the usb pendrive the "normal" way. Have you tried it without the "special" UEFI mode?

Comment: In my bios this option is not present and usb itself detected as UEFI:<usb name> in boot menu. From the boot menu I am selecting this option, even though the USB is not booting.